# Moving n items between i destinations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, greedy

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this problem, and I would appreciate some guidence on how to approach it.

The problem is as follows:

- We are given an array of grocerie stores, where the value is the
  distance between them e.g [0,5,10,15,20] (5km between each store)
- We are given an array of the inventory of apples at each store e.g
  [10,5,10,20,5] (first store has 10 apples in stock, second has 5,
  third has 10 etc.)

A man moves the apples between the stores, but he eats 2 apples pr. km. I have to make a function taking the two arrays as input, and outputting the largest amount of apples each store can have. This is a subtask in an assignment concerning greedy algorithms.

This is my idea of approaching it so far:

Find the store with the most apples, and distribute to the adjacent store with least apples. Running this recursively would leave me with an fairly evenly distributed amount of apples between the stores, but only looking at adjacent stores makes my solution less optimal. How should I approach this, and is this similar to any other generic problem in computer science?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what the output is supposed to be. Do you want, for each store, how many apples it could possibly have in isolation? If so that's just the simple arithmetic of moving all the apples from each store to that one. Or do you want the largest sum of all apples in all stores? If so the answer is always to do nothing. So I suspect what you're after is something else but I don't understand what.

Comment: @jacobm I think it's clear. _Output is the largest amount of apples of which each store can have._

Comment: @snr independently or simultaneously? But in either case I don't see what the problem has to do with greedy algorithms, which led me to believe that the OP may not have stated all the constraints.

Comment: @jacobm I want the most amount of apples x, so that each store has this amount as minimum in stock.

Comment: Show us the desired output. If you have the stores and inventory as you described in your two bullet points, what do you want the output to be? Would it be `[10,10,10,10,10]` if your driver didn't have a insatiable hunger for apples?

Comment: The initial setup is the most apples the stores can have as a whole. Any movement has a cost. You can move apples from one store to another, which may increase one store's count, but only at the expense of another's. There's not enough info to know if that's an improvement or not.

Comment: Also, if moving apples cost 2 apples/km and the stores are 5 km apart, it costs 10 apples to move from one store to it's neighbor. That would suggest you can only move apples from the fourth store and have any left at the end of the trip. Seems like something is missing or wrong.

Comment: Just to clarify: The lists I gave were just simplified examples, but I see why they are bad - their proportions make it impossible to improve the x amount of apples each store has. If you imagine one of the stores has 100 apples, then the task makes more sense. However, I just found out today that the algorithm should have a runtime of O(n), which eliminates alot of possibilities, and leaves me to try a variation of my initial approach. Thanks for your input.